# Why can I install Numpy, but not another library while my pip version is the lastest version?

Tags: pycharm

Currently I'm working with multiple people on a python project. We are working with Github. I connected Git with Pycharm.

There is a main file and in that main file there are libraries imported to support the functionality of the project. The installation of Numpy went flawless, but I have other libraries, such as SimPEG, that are less popular and won't get installed.

I tried to trouble shoot this by reading other posts, but the solution stated doesn't work. My pip version is 20.3.3.

When I try to install simpeg I get the following error:

[image]

Import code:

[image]

Link to simpeg:

https://docs.simpeg.xyz/content/basic/installing.html

Comment: Are you sure SimPEG and other packages support Python 3.9? Did you try to run `pip install SimPEG` as the window suggests?

Answer (score 0):

To install `SimPEG` via `pip`, you have to install Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 Build Tools.

You can find information on this issue [here](https://github.com/benfred/implicit/issues/76)